# How do I create a new cocos3D project for iPad using xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I installed Cocos 2D (Sprite builder version 1.3.5) and then Cocos 3D (version 2.0.1).

I can´t create Cocos 3D projects. after installing cocos3D I can see only 'cocos3D static library'  template in xcode (as in this screenshot) [image: xcode]  but not Cocos3D application template

and If I create new project using 'cocos3D static library' template, it will have a 'target of static library.a' but not .app target

As per the Readme file instructions i copy pasted 'hello world' project from distribution folder to my workspace and tried to run it,,but build failed by this error [image: error]  , I tried by re installing cocos2d and 3d but i couldnt fix it,,, pls help me out to fix this

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither **Cocos3D** nor *Cocos2D* support Xcode template projects anymore.

The `README.md` document in the **Cocos3D** distribution contains instructions about how to install **Cocos3D** into an existing *SpriteBuilder* or *Cocos2D* project.

Be aware that **Cocos3D 2.0.1** has not yet been validated for *SpriteBuilder 1.3* and *Cocos2D 3.3*.